# Device orientation not detecting in Today widget for iPhone device 4s,5,5s and 6

Tags: ios, swift

I am using below code to check orientation of device in today widget code base
but when I change mode to landscape for device iPhone 4s, 5, 5s and 6 then below code won't work.

let orientationSize: CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
        if (orientationSize.width / orientationSize.height > 1) {
            numberOfEvents = isiPad ? ipadLandscapeModeNumberOfEvents : iphoneLandscapeModeNumberOfEvents
        }

I have tried below methods and all are won't work

- override fun viewWillTransitionToSize
- override fun willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

I am stuck in this long time.

Please note that issue is only for iPhone 4s,5,5s and 6.

[image: constraints 1]
[image]

Comment: it is hard to tell anything for sure without seeing your _constraints_ in the extension.

Comment: but it works fine for all devices except mention in question.And also it works fine for all devices in portrait mode.The issue is for only landscape mode.

Comment: that is why it must be important to see / check your _constraints_ because probably you have not sent them at all, but you have created the layout for portrait orientation with no constraint and you'd expect the miracle to happen automatically; but in such case it will not.

Comment: @holex:Let me know if you want more information

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the bounds (size) before the orientation change within:

```
willRotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

so that will show you current size before orientation actually changes. I suggest you to check the size with

```
CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
```

within following method:

```
didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation
```